# How do i make my fixed sidebar to stay in one spot even when I scroll the main content

Tags: html, css, sidebar

When I make my web page smaller the sidebar goes on top of the main content, how can I make it stay on the side [image]

here is an example of what happens

Comment: I'm guessing that the content of the page remains too wide and needs to be made narrower, perhaps with a `@media` query. However, it's very hard to answer without seeing your code and your own attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: Hi. We need code to see what is happening. Could you add it?

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap, you can use something similar to this. This is simply an example but it can be applied to help change this when the screen resizes.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 575px) {
 font-size: 55px;
}
```

This means that when the screen has a max width of 575px, then the font-size would change to 55px. Without your code I can't give you a more exact answer but you can apply this concept to the issue you have. Hope this helps!